# Как уменшить размер exe файла python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

Я сделал простую программу в python с помощью pyqt5. Потом я сделал .exe файл с помощью auto-py-to-exe. Окончательный размер был 28мб. Можно ли как нибудь уменшить размер .exe файла?

Comment: 1 - Переписать на что-то компилируемое (тогда не придется вшивать интерпретатор внутрь экзешника). 2 - переписать без QT, потому что сами dll библиотеки весят по несколько мегабайт скорее всего.

Comment: Есть еще вариант - смириться с несовершенством мира, и оставить как есть.

Comment: незнаю поможет ли, но попробуйте собрать с помощью pyinstaller, nuitka  у nuitka вообще размер файлов обычно поменьше

Comment: @FotonPC pyintaller точно так же вшивает в готовый файл интерпретатор Python, все нужные библиотеки, в том числе библиотеку QT. Преимущества перед auto-py-to-exe не будет. Nuitka частично компилирует код, размер скорее всего будет немного меньше, но python.dll все равно будет требоваться для работы, точно так же как и QT.

Comment: программы использующие Qt в любом случае потащат за собой библиотеки самой Qt. Даже статически собранный комплект Qt и c++ приложение. Как минимум это будет QtBase + platforms и QtWidgets (если хоть какой-то gui есть)

Answer (score 0):

Подумайте, так ли Вам нужен Qt. Может и Tkinter будет достаточно.

Это должно уменьшить размер файла. Qt - сторонняя библиотека, а Tkinter "вшит" в стандартную библиотеку Python.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Автор нигде не писал, что использует Qt, это было предположение из комментариев.

Comment: В первом предложении автор пишет: "Я сделал простую программу в python с помощью pyqt5." В тегах  также PyQt5.